# Why does Gus Fring speak bad Spanish but good English?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

Why does Gus Fring speak bad Spanish (with the accent of a stereotypical bad beginning American student) but good (perfectly American accented) English?

The out-of-universe explanation would be that the actor playing this character (Giancarlo Esposito) is American.

But I was wondering whether there's any plausible in-universe explanation?

Back story according to [Fandom](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gustavo_Fring):

> He claims to be from Chile, and is sometimes referred to by cartel members as "The Chilean", but it is unclear whether or not he was born there as no records of his life exist prior to 1986 ... Sometime during the 1980s, Gus fled Chile and in 1986 settled in Mexico ... Soon after, Gus emigrated to the United States and expanded his restaurant business.

Could it be that he actually grew up in the US?

Comment: Giancarlo Esposito is not American; he is Danish.

Comment: @MichaelLorton He's American. Born in Denmark, but grew up in the US. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giancarlo_Esposito

Comment: Anyways, he never lived in any spanish speaking countries ever. He looks latino though.

Comment: Does he really speak good (perfectly American accented) English? I thought he speaks somehow weird (in comparison to e.g. Saul, Mike).

Comment: Discussions about his accent when speaking Spanish have taken place many times on Reddit and Quora: https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/znjzwz/gus_frings_spanish/, https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/1s1m11/gustavo_frings_spanish/, https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/k90ij/spanish_accent_in_breaking_bad_is_driving_me_crazy/, https://www.quora.com/On-Breaking-Bad-Do-Spanish-speakers-find-Giancarlo-Espositos-accent-when-hes-speaking-Spanish-distracting, https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/zfvf7/does_hector_salamanca_and_gus_frings_poor_native/,

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/ffq26t/gus_frings_spanish_sucks_anyone_else_noticed_it/. I searched for those because I remember this being discussed online before (I at first thought it was from this site, Movies.SE, but there's 80+ questions that are provided when I search `[breaking-bad] gus is:question` and after looking at several, I started to think I might have seen the discussion elsewhere). Anyway, it has been discussed before, and I'm quite sure I remember people saying that the show caters to a US audience that isn't expected to notice.